# Создание новых todo по Enter

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Пытаюсь добавить часть кода, позволяющая по нажатию кнопки Enter создавать новое дело. Но при добавлении кода, перестает все работать, и ошибку не выдает.....
прошу помочь))

```
window.onload = function(){

    var todoList = [];
    var stored = localStorage.getItem('todo');
    if (stored)
    todoList = JSON.parse(stored);
    out();
    document.getElementById('add').onclick = function(){
        var d = document.getElementById('in').value;

        var temp = {};
        temp.todo = d;
        temp.check = false;
        var i = todoList.length;
        todoList[i] = temp;
        console.log(todoList);
        out();
        localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todoList) );
        localStorage.getItem('todo');
    }

    createOnEnter: function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
      if (!this.input.val()) return;

      Todos.create({title: this.input.val()});
      this.input.val('');
    }

    function out()
    {
        var out = '';
        for (var key in todoList){
            if (todoList[key].check == true){
                out += '<input type="checkbox" checked>';
            }
            else {
                out += '<input type="checkbox">';
            }
            out += todoList[key].todo + '<br>';

        }
        document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = out;

    }
}
```

Comment: `createOnEnter: function(e) {` - что это за кусок кода? откуда он взялся?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function createOnEnter(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13)
    document.getElementById('add').click();
}

window.addEventListener("keyup", createOnEnter);
```

```html
<button id="add" onclick="console.log('AAA')">Add</button>
```